# $a > b, (a - b)(b - c)(c - a) > 0$ Which is bigger, $a$ or $c$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$a > b$
$(a - b)(b - c)(c - a) > 0$
Which is bigger, $a$ or $c$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$a-b$ is positive, so $b-c$ and $c-a$ have the same sign. Then
$$a<c<b\text{ or }b<c<a$$
Since $b<a$ then the first option is false, so $a>c$.

Comment: ummm, We are given $a>b$, so the first option is false, so $c\lt a$.

Comment: True. Just a silly mistake. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Let us assume $c>a>b$. Then, we have $(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)<0$ because of $a-b>0,b-c<0,c-a>0$.

Therefore we can rule out $c>a$.

$a=c$ would imply $(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)=0$, so is impossible as well.

Therefore we can conclude $c<a$

Comment: If we have $b<c<a$ , we have $a-b>0$ ,  $b-c<0$ , $c-a<0$, so in this case, both conditions are met.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a\lt c$

It follows that $b\gt c$ so  that the initial condition

$(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)\gt 0$ holds true. ( If two of the terms within the parentheses are positive, the other one must be as well )

But $a\gt b$. A contradiction. Thus $a\gt c$.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time! You say "It follows that $b > c$" but it should be reversed if $a < c$ (from your first assumption it should be like $c < a < b$).

Comment: @My pleasure! Well, methinks it shouldn't since that "so that" is present in the sentence linking the argument..

Comment: @Estonian I was curious about that too. It *does* follow that $b > c$ by considering signs (and it's worth mentioning *something* to that effect). So in reality, the contradiction has already shown itself, as this violates transitivity of $<$.

Comment: @pjs36 I dare say we are caught in a "nominalistic" argument. I suppose I could have written: It follows that $b\gt c$ so that the initial condition $(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)\gt 0$ is true..

Comment: Yeah, I think you're right. I was expecting the justification *before* the conclusion; so I lost my train of thought a bit and couldn't process how it all came together.

Answer (score 0):

Remember $k < j; x > 0$ then $kx < jx$ and $k/x < j/x$ and if $k < j; y < 0$ then $ky > jy$ and $k/y > j/y$.

Or in imformal terms "multiplying or dividing by a positive keeps the less than/greater than sign; multiplying or dividing by a negative flips it".

$a > b$ so $a - b>0$.

So if $(a-b)(b -c)(c-a) > 0$ then dividing be $a-b$ will "keep the sign"

$(b -c)(c-a) > 0$.  So either  $(b-c)$ and $(c-a)$ are both positive; or they are both negative.

If they are both positive then $b > c$ and $c > a$.  SO $b > c > a$ and $b > a$.  But we know that is not true.

If the are both negative then $b<c$ and $c < a$ and $a > b$ which is consistant with what we already know

So:  $a > b; c>a;$ and $c>b$ so

$(a-b) > 0$

$(a-b)(b-c) < 0$ and

$(a-b)(b-c)(c-a) > 0$.